# The equality of quotient subgroups $NM/M$ and $N/M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $N$ and $M$ are normal subgroups of $G$. Is true that $NM/M=N/M?$

Since $NM/M=\{Mg:g\in NM\}$ and $N/M=\{Mg:g\in N\}$.

Let $x\in N/M$ then $x=Mg$ for $g\in N$ and $N=Ne\subset NM$ so $x=Mg$ where $g\in NM$. Hence $x\in NM/M$. Thus $N/M\subset NM/M$ and the converse inclusion can be proved the same way. Therefore, $N/M=NM/M$.

Is this proof correct?

**EDIT:** We know that $M$ is normal in $G$, i.e. for any $g\in G$ we have: $gMg^{-1}=M$ or $gM=Mg$

Let's quotient set $N/M$ be the of all right cosets of $M$ in $N$, i.e. $N/M=\{Mn: n\in N\}$. We can prove that this set is a group if we consider it under the following operation: $Mn_1\cdot Mn_2=Mn_1n_2$. In this case al axioms of group will be correct. So even if $M$ is not a subgroup of $N$ we can consider $N/M$ as a group. What's wrong?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, Since $M$ is a subgroup of $NM$ and $M$ is normal then quotient set $NM/M$ is a group.

Comment: Then $N/M$ need not be a group, because we do not know that $M$ is a normal subgroup of $N$. In fact, $M$ need not be a subgroup of $N$ at all.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, You are right. $N/M$ may not be a group. But what is wrong with proof above? I have proven the double inclusion.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, No. What if we will consider them as cosets? In this case are they equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cosets of $M$ in $N$ are usually defined for $M\subseteq N$, see wikipedia.
But then the claim is obvious anyway in the group situation, by the third isomorphism theorem

$$
NM/M\cong N/(N\cap M)=N/M.
$$

Comment: Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: You still have not $M\subseteq N$ in your edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this remark. So in order to consider cosets of $M$ in $N$ we need to have $M\subset N$. Otherwise, it is meaningless, right?

Comment: Otherwise it is not a [coset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset), yes.

Comment: Even if $M$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ which is not contained in another subgroup $N$, we can still define $N/M$ to be  $$N/M = \{ nM : n \in N \}$$ which is the image of $N$ in $G/M$.  Then $N/M$ is a subgroup of $G/N$, equal to $NM/M$.

Comment: @D_S The definition of coset requires $M\subseteq N$, see wikipedia; so I am not sure why you would downvote.

Comment: Dear, Dietrich! Thanks a lot. You have streamlined my knowledge on group theory. I was considering this structures in order to prove above isomorphism theorem which you have written but I was not able to do it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde as long as $N$ and $M$ are subgroups of a larger group, $N/M$ makes perfect sense as a subset of cosets of $M$ in $G$.

Comment: I mean no disrespect, but I downvoted because your answer does not exactly address the OP's question, as they are specifically not assuming $M \subseteq N$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi: G \rightarrow H$ is a surjective group homomorphism, and $N$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $\phi(N)$ is a subgroup of $H$.  Under the correspondence theorem, $P \mapsto \phi(P)$ is a bijection between the subgroups of $G$ which contain $\operatorname{Ker}\phi$ and the subgroups of $H$.  The unique subgroup of $G$ containing $\operatorname{Ker}\phi$ to which $\phi(N)$ corresponds is $N.\operatorname{Ker}\phi$.

If you let $M = \operatorname{Ker}\phi$ and identify $H$ with $G/M$ and $\phi$ with $g \mapsto gM$ via the first isomorphism theorem, you recover the answer to your question.